How to transpose blocks of data (tables) within a gnuplot readable file?
How can several data blocks be transposed within a file? Each data block begins with a line '# description' and ends with two empty lines. A typical input file looks like this:
# block_01
Temp    ST_01       ST_02       ST_03       ST_04
ag7     -0.0295167  0.0553285   0.00883727  0.392553
bc9     -0.0513702  0.0355596   -0.0165404  0.252816
cc9     -0.0303508  -0.00354388 0.0428582   0.0882037
cd3     -0.0239757  -0.0363891  0.0227775   0.270722


# block_02
Temp    ST_01       ST_02       ST_03       ST_04
ag7.b   -0.00284193 0.0260536   0.163357    -0.17291
bc9.b   -0.0212977  0.0191269   0.0330521   -0.17346  
cc9.b   -0.0138837  -0.0220729  0.0814398   -0.0478094
cd3.f   -0.053152   -0.0041982  -0.0948933  -0.020557


# block_03
Temp    ST_01       ST_02       ST_03       ST_04
...

The desired output file after transposition should look as follows:
# block_01
Temp    ag7         bc9         cc9         cd3
ST_01   -0.0295167  -0.0513702  -0.0303508  -0.0239757
ST_02   0.0553285   0.0355596   -0.00354388 -0.0363891
ST_03   0.00883727  -0.0165404  0.0428582   0.0227775
ST_04   0.392553    0.252816    0.0882037   0.270722


# block_02
Temp    ag7.b       bc9.b       cc9.b       cd3.f  
ST_01   -0.00284193 -0.0212977  -0.0138837  -0.053152  
ST_02   0.0260536   0.0191269   -0.0220729  -0.0041982  
ST_03   0.163357    0.0330521   0.0814398   -0.0948933  
ST_04   -0.17291    -0.17346    -0.0478094  -0.020557


# block_03
Temp    ag7.b       bc9.b       cc9.b       cd3.f  
...

It does not necessarily have to be done only in gnuplot. Scripts in bash or awk are also welcome.

Have you checked this? Certainly not ultra-efficient, but gnuplot-only. Needs to be adapted to your special case. What do you actually want to plot? Maybe it could be done even without transposing?

@theozh: Oh yes, that's a good start. And gnuplot-only, my preferred choice...

Have you already managed it? Do you actually need to (or want to) keep the block titles?

@theozh: I need the titles of the blocks because they show different measurement conditions.

Here is a more general solution which is gnuplot-only (based on this solution) and works for multiple blocks each with different number of rows and columns.
Data: SO79102179.dat
# block_01
Temp   a1    b1    c1    d1
A1     11    12    13    14
B1     21    22    23    24
C1     31    32    33    34
D1     41    43    43    44
E1     51    52    53    54
F1     61    62    64    64


# block_02
Temp  a2    b2    c2    d2    e2    f2
A2    11    12    13    14    15    16
B2    21    22    23    24    25    26
C2    31    32    33    34    35    36

Script: (works for gnuplot>=5.4.0, because of with table if ...)
### transpose each of multiple blocks 
reset session

FILE = "SO79102179.dat"

stats FILE u (B=column(-2)) nooutput    # B = highest block index
do for [b=0:B]{
    stats FILE index b u 0 nooutput     # get max. number of rows and columns
    R = STATS_records
    C = STATS_columns
    set datafile commentschar '' separator "\n"
    set table $Transposed append
        plot FILE index b u (_s=strcol(1)) w table if _s[1:1] eq '#'    # write comment lines
    unset table
    set datafile commentschar '#' separator whitespace  # restore default
    set table $Transposed append
        plot for [i=1:C] FILE index b u ($0==0 ? Line=strcol(i) : Line=Line.' '.strcol(i)) w table if $0==R-1, \
        '+' every ::::1 u ('') w table   # add two empty lines
    unset table
}
print $Transposed

### end of script

Result:
# block_01
Temp A1 B1 C1 D1 E1 F1
a1 11 21 31 41 51 61
b1 12 22 32 43 52 62
c1 13 23 33 43 53 64
d1 14 24 34 44 54 64


# block_02
Temp A2 B2 C2
a2 11 21 31
b2 12 22 32
c2 13 23 33
d2 14 24 34
e2 15 25 35
f2 16 26 36


I particularly like this gnuplot-only version because my colleagues under Windows can also work with it. I also have files with tables of different sizes. So far, I have simply avoided working with them. Instead, I have edited such files manually by copying tables of the same size into separate files.

# transpose data in file (rows to columns)
# repect blank lines separating data
conv -U < "$1" | gawk '
BEGIN {
   #   FS = "\t" # include for tab delimited data if items contain white space
   i = 1
   jmax = 0
   got_data = 0 # indicator for data blocks
}
/^#/ { # pass comments thru
   print
   got_data = 0
   next
}
/^$/ && got_data == 1 { # blank line - print data transposed
   jend = jmax - 1
   iend = i - 1
   for (j = 1; j <= jend; j++) {
      printf "%s", list[1, j]
      for (i = 2; i <= iend; i++) {
         printf "\t%s", list[i, j]
      }
      printf ("\n")  # linefeed after each row
   }
   got_data = 0
   i = 1
   jmax = 0
   print
   next
}
/^$/ { # print additional blank lines that exist
   print
   next
}
{
   # save data in array
   for (j = 1; j <= NF; j++) {
      list[i, j] = $j
   }
   if (j > jmax) {
      jmax = j
   }
   i++
   got_data = 1 # indicate data block found
}
END { # print data transposed
   if (got_data == 0) {
      exit
   }
   jend = jmax - 1
   iend = i - 1
   for (j = 1; j <= jend; j++) {
      printf "%s", list[1, j]
      for (i = 2; i <= iend; i++) {
         printf "\t%s", list[i, j]
      }
      if (j < jend) {
         printf ("\n")  # linefeed after each row (except the last row)
      }
   }
}
'

conv -U converts crlf to lf in cygwin for UNIX and could be eliminated if not needed.
also, FS = "\t" is there to use this with tab delimited data.

I edited my post to manage data including comments and multiple data blocks separated by single or multiple blank lines

saving this code as an awk script and executing it via gnuplot system works.
